# Entity mapping using a non primary key column

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am using hibernate and Mysql in the java project for persistence.
I have two entities **Transaction** and **Service**. Transaction is having many to one relation to service. 
I wanted to use a non primary column(SERVICE_CODE) of type VARCHAR from Service table as a foreign key in the Transaction table. But when I do so I get the following exception.

```
SQL Error: 1452, SQLState: 23000
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails.
```

SERVICE_CODE is defined as non null and unique in database.
Following example works fine if I use primary key from Service table for mapping.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Transaction")
public class Transaction {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="TRANSACTION_ID")
    long transactionId;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="SERVICE_CODE")
    Service service;
}


@Entity
@Table(name="SERVICE")
public class Service {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="SERVICE_ID")
    Long serviceId;

    @Column(name="SERVICE_CODE")
    String serviceCode; 
}
```

Comment: Please reopen it, as I have edited the question and added the example code as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-a-manytoone-association-using-a-non-primary-key-column/), you should use the [`referencedColumnName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html#referencedColumnName%28%29) attribute of the `@JoinColumn` annotation to specify the referenced column of the foreign key relationship.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="SERVICE_CODE", referencedColumnName="SERVICE_CODE")
Service service;
```

With this modification the DDL is generated correctly like this:

```
alter table Transaction
    add constraint FK_5k37nrtsvi22y2jhsde903ps9
    foreign key (SERVICE_CODE)
    references SERVICE (SERVICE_CODE);
```

and with your original code like this (it references primary key of the `SERVICE` table instead of the `SERVICE_CODE` column):

```
alter table Transaction
    add constraint FK_5k37nrtsvi22y2jhsde903ps9
    foreign key (SERVICE_CODE)
    references SERVICE;
```